# Does \hangafter has any effect when \hangindent is zero?

Tags: tex-core

TeXbook p.103 says:

> You get the normal paragraph
>   shape, in which every line width is \hsize, when \parshape=0, \hangindent=0pt, and \hangafter=1.

IMHO, when `\hangindent` is zero, `\hangafter` has no effect.

Can anybody think of an example where one gets not "normal paragraph shape" using `\hangafter=X`, where `X` is different from `1`? (considering `\parshape=0` and `\hangindent=0pt`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the text say that with `\hangindent=0pt \hangafter=1000` you don't get the “normal paragraph shape”?

This code typesets the same paragraphs:

```
\input plipsum

\hangindent=0pt \hangafter=-1
\lipsum 1

\hangindent=0pt \hangafter=20
\lipsum 1

\parshape 1 0pt \hsize
\lipsum 1

\bye
```

What the text says is that the values to which the parameters are reset are

```
\parshape=0
\hangindent=0pt
\hangafter=1
```

There's no other implication. Here's the quotation (third paragraph on page 103):

> If `\parshape` and hanging indentation have both been specified, `\parshape` takes precedence and `\hangindent` is ignored. You get the normal paragraph shape, in which every line width is `\hsize`, when `\parshape=0`, `\hangindent=0pt`, and `\hangafter=1`. TeX automatically restores these normal values at the end of every paragraph, and (by local definitions) whenever it enters internal vertical mode.

If you only set `\hangindent`, it will have effect starting from the second line, which is what's normally desired.